# Specflow bypasses subsequent scenarios after a failure

Tags: specflow

All scenarios do what they are supposed to but, until now, I only had 1.

Now that I have a second scenario, the following problem arises.

If the scenario 1 fails an assertion, the subsequent scenarios are skipped.

See below the skipped scenarios.

```
Setup: ConfigFileTransformation (thread #0)
Scenario: Shows telephone numbers on the header in ShowContactInformation
    (target: BrowserBrowserStack_Win8_Chrome_52) -> Succeeded on thread #0
Scenario: Shows telephone numbers on the contact sidebar box in
    ShowContactInformation (target: BrowserBrowserStack_Win8_Chrome_52)
    -> Failed on thread #0
    [ERROR] 2 assertions failed.
Restore: ConfigFileTransformation (thread #0)
Scenario: Shows telephone numbers on the header in ShowContactInformation
    (target: BrowserBrowserStack_Win8_Firefox_42)
    -> Skipped on thread #-1
Scenario: Shows telephone numbers on the contact sidebar box in
    ShowContactInformation
    (target: BrowserBrowserStack_Win8_Firefox_42)
    -> Skipped on thread #-1
Result: 1 failed
  Total: 4
  Succeeded: 1
  Ignored: 0
  Pending: 0
  Skipped: 2 <--- **** Other scenarios must be executed regardless of anything else.
  Failed: 1
```

How do I prevent specflow from skipping subsequent scenarios?

Comment: Which test runner are you using? Specrun?

Comment: I had tried NUnit and SpecRun separately. No difference but the answer now explains what was my problem. Thanks @SamHolder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the Execution element of the test profile to:

```
<Execution retryFor="None" stopAfterFailures="0" testThreadCount="1" testSchedulingMode="Sequential" />
```

The key thing seems to be `stopAfterFailures="0"`.